# Put a node into another with simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

This my base xml structure :

```
<Module_Files>  
        <Category name="categorie1">
        </Category>
</Module_Files>
```

I want to add in the category node another node like this :

```
<Module_Files>  
        <Category name="categorie1">
             <file lan="fr>
                 <title>  ....  </title>
                 <path>   ....  </path>
             </file>
        </Category>
</Module_Files>
```

But I can't

This my code :

```
$xmlFile->xpath("//Category[@name='" . $categoryName . "']"); //$categoryName = "categorie1"

$nodeFile = $xmlFile->addChild("file", "");
$nodeFile->addAttribute("lang", (string) $data["lang"]);   
$nodeFile->addChild("titre", (string) $data["titre"]);
$nodeFile->addChild("path", (string) $data["path"]);
```

This code add the file node after the category node and not into.. like this :

```
<Module_Files>  
   <Category name="categorie1">
   </Category>
   <file lan="fr>
      <title>  ....  </title>
      <path>   ....  </path>
      </file>
</Module_Files>
```

How can I do to put the file node into the category node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not assign result of xpath, so you add child to root element, not to category element. Try this:

```
$categories = $xmlFile->xpath("//Category[@name='" . $categoryName . "']"); //$categoryName = "categorie1"

if (isset($categories[0])) {
  $nodeFile = $categories[0]->addChild("file", "");
  $nodeFile->addAttribute("lang", (string) $data["lang"]);   
  $nodeFile->addChild("titre", (string) $data["titre"]);
  $nodeFile->addChild("path", (string) $data["path"]);
} else {
  echo 'Not found Category node with name: '.$categoryName.PHP_EOL;
}
```